# Find all objects related to a list of transport requests

Tags: transport, sap-basis

I have a huge list of transport requests, I want to get a report of all included objects of these (as a "sum-up"). I couldn't find a report in transaction `SE03`, `SE09`, `SE10`, nor in Transport Organizer Tools.
Help is appreciated.

Comment: check this out, trying to get a SAP stack exchange started http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41621/sap-systems-applications-and-products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out, use SE11, goto table E071, filter by TRKORR (multiple selection is possible), group result in Grid Display by PGMID, OBJECT and OBJ_NAME.

Comment: This works well. Note that you can simplify the grouping by using the [SE16H transaction](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ERPFI/How+to+use+transaction+code+SE16h+to+quickly+determine+the+number+of+Financial+Documents+for+each+Company+Code+in+your+system) if it's available on your system. See SAP Note [1636416](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1636416) for details on that transaction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a standard report for that but these are the tables in SAP where you can get that information to make a Z report:

E070:  Change & Transport System: Header of Requests/Tasks

E07T: Change & Transport System: Short Texts for Requests/Tasks

E071:  Change & Transport System: Object Entries of Requests/Tasks <--- Here are the objects to be transported.

E070A: Change & Transport System: Attributes of a Request

E070C: CTS: Source/Target Client of Requests/Tasks

In the case of table 'E070' there's a relationship with itself between fields 'TRKORR' (Request/Task) and 'STRKORR' (Higher-Level Request).

Hope it helps.